# Calculation of conditional expexctation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, projection

I struggle to calculate a conditional expectation:
Let $X$ be a random variable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with density function $\alpha$.  Further, let $\eta$ be a unit vector and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function.
I already know that the density function of the random variable $\langle \eta, X \rangle$ is $\rho(y) := \int_{\{x:\langle \eta,x\rangle = y\}} \alpha(x) \;d\lambda_{n-1}(x)$.
Now I need to prove the following statement:
\begin{equation}\mathbb{E}(g(X) \vert \langle \eta, X \rangle) = \frac{\int_{\{x:\langle \eta,x\rangle =y\}} g(x)\alpha(x) \;d\lambda_{n-1}(x)}{\rho(y)}.
\end{equation}

This is what I've tried: 
If we denote $Z:= g(X)$,$Y:= \langle \eta, X \rangle$ and $f_{Z,Y}$ as the joint density function of $Z$ and $Y$ then according to wikipedia,
\begin{equation}
f_{Z\vert Y} (z,y) = \frac{f_{Z,Y}(z,y)}{\int_? f_{Z,Y}(u,y) du} 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(Z \vert Y) = \int_? z \cdot f_{Z\vert Y} (z,Y)\;dz.
\end{equation}
Comparing this to the solution we are tying to get, it looks a like $\alpha$ was treated as the joint PDF of $Z$ and $Y$. But I don't understand why we can do that. Shouldn't  $f_{Z,Y}$ be a function $\mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, while $\alpha:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?
I am very confused about this.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know the density $\alpha(x)$ of $X$ and the density $\rho(y)$ of $Y=\langle\eta,X\rangle$ and want to calculate the function
$$
h(y):=\mathbb E[\,g(X)|Y=y\,]. 
$$
The trick is to choose a Borel set $A\subset\mathbb R$ and just use the properties of the conditional expectation:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_A\int_{\{x:\langle \eta,x\rangle\, =\, y\}}g(x)\,\alpha(x)\,dx\,dy&=&\mathbb E[\,g(X)1_{\{Y\in A\}}\,]=\mathbb E[\,\mathbb E[\,g(X)\,1_{\{Y\in A\}}|Y\,]\,]\\&=&
E[\,\mathbb E[\,g(X)|Y\,]\,1_{\{Y\in A\}}\,]=\int_Ah(y)\,\rho(y)\,dy\\
&=&\int_Ah(y)\int_{\{x:\langle \eta,x\rangle\, =\, y\}} \alpha(x)\,dx\,dy.
\end{eqnarray*}
Using the fact that $A$ was an arbitrary Borel set and
comparing the first and last term in this chain of equations shows
$$
h(y)=\frac{\int_{\{x:\langle \eta,x\rangle\, =\, y\}}g(x)\,\alpha(x)\,dx}{\int_{\{x:\langle \eta,x\rangle\, =\, y\}} \alpha(x)\,dx}=\frac{\int_{\{x:\langle \eta,x\rangle\, =\, y\}}g(x)\,\alpha(x)\,dx}{\rho(y)}.
$$

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I have one question though: Why can we just compare the first and last term and then deduce $h(y)=...$? I see that it works the other way around but different functions can have the same integral, so why do we get this unique solution for $h(y)$?

Comment: Let me know if you agree with the following (then I can add this to the answer): we build the chain of equations around $\mathbb E[g(X);Y\in A]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[g(X)|Y];Y\in A]$. Then the $\mathbb R$ in the outer integral becomes an arbitrary Borel set $A$. This should allow only the wanted solution for $h(y)$.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand what you mean by the first sentence. Could you elaborate this please? I do agree, that IF the equation$ \int_{A}\int_{\{x:\langle \eta,x \rangle=y\}} g(x) \alpha(x) dx dy = \int_{A} h(y)\int_{\{x:\langle \eta,x \rangle=y\}}  \alpha(x) dx dy$ holds for any Borel set A, then there is an (a.s.) unique solution for $h(y)$.

Comment: @maiktheissen. My edit of the answer should clarify this.